# Fetch argument and maintain state of argparse parser in python

Tags: python, namespaces, command-line-arguments, argparse

I am trying to parse arguments using argparse module in python. I have two parser objects of the same instance - main parser and secondary parser.

The arguments parsed using secondary parser need to be hooked at runtime to the arguments parsed using main parser which I am able to do successfully only if I run main parser.parseArgs() once.

What I am interested in doing is to fetch a value of an argument parsed using secondary parser and then pass that argument to the main parser. I tried to run secondary parser.parseArgs() but this results into issues as the runtime hooking to the main parser fails. I think, I can probably solve this issue using namespace objects in argparse but don't know how to do it. Could somebody help with this ?

```
    secondaryparser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
    secondaryparser.add_Argument('--c')
    args2= secondaryparser.parseArgs()
    print args2.c

    mainparser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
    mainparser.add_Argument('--a')
    mainparser.add_Argument('--b')
    args = mainparser.parseArgs()
    print args.a, args.b
```

From what I understand, parseArgs() looks into it's own namespace and pops out each argument and empties the stack and hence the second parseArgs() call fails. In this context, how can we save the state of the secondary parser and pass the argument to the main parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a guess as to what you are trying to do.  I'm going to make the use of `sys.argv` explicit, so it is clear what is going on.

```
import sys
print sys.argv

secondaryparser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
secondaryparser.add_argument('--c')
args2, extras2 = secondaryparser.parse_known_args(sys.argv[1:])
print args2  # diagnositic display of the Namespace
print extras
print args2.c

mainparser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
mainparser.add_argument('--a')
mainparser.add_argument('--b')
args, extras = mainparser.parse_known_args(sys.argv[1:], args2)
# args = mainparser.parse_args(extras2, args2)
print args.a, args.b
print args2  # debug
print args   # debug
print extras
```

`secondaryparser` is setup to look for `--c` in the list of arguments from the command line.  I'm using `parse_known_args` so it won't raise an error if you include `--a` or `--b`.  If present, those strings will appear in the `extras2` list.

`mainparser` could be called with `mainparser.parse_args()`, but it would raise an error if you included `--c`.  Instead I used `parse_known_args` again, or pass it `extras2` which already has the `--c` removed.

`args` and `args2` should be the same namespace after this call, and should contain `a`,`b` and `c` attributes.

With `parse_known_args` and the namespace argument, you can chain a number of parsers, all using the same input.  The output of `parse_known_args` is the only 'state' of the parse that you can access - it's the namespace containing parsed strings, and a list of strings it couldn't handle.

A parser isn't a state machine.  It's an object (class `ArgparseParser`) that 'owns' a number of arguments (`argparse.Action` objects).  `parse_args` is a method that takes a list of strings, and returns a Namespace object.  Nothing in the `parser` changes as a result of this call.  `parse_args` (or `parse_known_args`) could be called many times, repeatedly on the default  `sys.argv` (but why?) or on other (test) inputs.

Test code often looks like:

```
 parser = argparer.ArguementParser(...)
 ....
 print (parser.parse_args([])) # to see how it behaves without any commandline values)
 print (parser.parse_args(['-f', 'foovalue'])
 args = parser.parse_args()
 print (args)
 parser.print_help()
 try:
     parser.parse_args(['bad','value'])
 except <capture error ans sys.exit>
     print (error)
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. This does make few things clearer for me.  Precisely, I am trying to store the value of "c" so that I can pass that value to my helper function to do some extra manipulation and also pass "c" to the main parser where it could be appended to "a" and "b" and then do some other things with a,b and c collectively. My only need is to be able to use the value of "c" initially and still have "c" passed on to the main parser.

Answer (score 1):

The way I solved this problem is like this. Thanks to hpaulj for the approach.

```
known_args, unknown_args = secondaryparser.parse_known_args()
value_c = known_args.c 

finalargs = mainparser.parse_known_args(args=unknown_args, namespace=known_args)
```

Using parse_known_args, I was able to fetch the value of "C" beforehand. If you see the first block of code here, I returned a tuple of known and unknown args. I fetch the value of "C" using known_args.c and pass the unknown_Args to the main_parser with the namespace being "args". This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly an answer, but I couldn't make it fit in a comment.  I'm not precisely sure what you are trying to do.  If you call parser.parse_args with no parameters, it will parse the command line.  This will fail the way you've got it set up, because the arguments --a and --b are unknown to the secondary parser and the argument --c is unknown to the main parser, so they cannot both parse the same command line.

You cannot have run the code you're showing us, because ArgumentParser doesn't have methods named parseArgs and addArgument.  (They're parse_args and add_argument.)

You can parse a string with and ArgumentParser simply by passing the string as a parameter to parse_args, and I suppose that will work in your case, but it's hard to see why you can't just make one parser with arguments --a, --b and --c.  I suppose your real application must be much more complicated that the sample you gave.

I don't think your comments on popping the stack are apposite, in that you have two entirely different parsers, with different stacks.  I think you could parse the command line twice, but since the definition of the parsers would be essentially the same, it wouldn't accomplish anything (or at least, nothing obvious.)

I don't know if this helps at all.  If it doesn't, perhaps you could give us a better idea of what you need to do.

P.S. What I always do in complicated situations is to have a function named getArgs say, which gets all the arguments processes them as needed, modifies the args object returned by the ArgumentParser, and returns it. As a simple example, suppose I have a field named --extent and the user is supposed to enter an integer between 30 and 100, but I want it as a decimal.  My getArgs function validates the input, then does `args.extent *= .01`, and returns args.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Precisely, I am trying to store the value of "c" so that I can pass that value to my helper function to do some extra manipulation  and also pass "c" to the main parser where it could be appended to "a" and "b" and then do some other things with a,b and c collectively. My only need is to be able to use the value of "c" initially and still have "c" passed on to the main parser.

Comment: I added a postscript to my post, but hpaulj's reply is probably more useful to you.  I was unaware of parse_known_args, which seems like the way to go if my simplistic approach doesn't suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks saulspatz. I got it working. Just posted my solution.